# Native Mac timer app for Freshbooks

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

What's a Freshbooks-compatible native Mac time-tracking app that is still updated? I found a few that work on [Freshbooks's site](http://www.freshbooks.com/addons), but it looks like they haven't been updated in years. I can track via Freshbooks's web app, but I'd prefer not to have Safari running just for that. That's why I'd like to find a native Mac app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been using the freshbooks widget happily until recently when it started timing out due to the number of projects I was working on. I found the project on github, fixed the timeout issue and submitted a pull request. https://github.com/mxroo/osx-dashboard-widget

I'd say give the 1.0.6 version a go https://github.com/freshbooks/osx-dashboard-widget and see if it works.

Eon and others don't work for my workflow, as I need to have multiple timers open at the same time so I can quickly switch tasks.

Comment: Very cool. Can you provide some documentation on GitHub to teach a noobie like me how to get your widget up and running?

Comment: My updates have been merged into the master, so you can just download the widget by clicking "download zip" in the bottom right corner of the main github page https://github.com/freshbooks/osx-dashboard-widget, then open the widget from inside the zip.

Comment: I'm up and running with 1.0.6. How are you able to have multiple timers open at the same time? (I.e., how do you switch between tasks?)

Comment: Hey @mxroo, I found a tool that lets me show your widget on the desktop! http://db.lcs.mit.edu/madden/WidgetRunner/ via http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/177727/make-os-x-dashboard-widgets-appear-in-desktop#new-answer

Answer (score 2):

I use Chronomate. It's not technically native, but I've used the free version with great success. Mutliple timers too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe give Eon a try, it's ok but not great, seems the best available and is definitely updated regularly.  Developers even respond to emails :-)

https://software.charliemonroe.net/eon/

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I tried Eon. You're right. It does the job, but it's not great. Its interface is so counter-intuitive that I'm never quite sure I actually submitted my hours to Freshbooks. I'm afraid I can't rely on it for my time tracking. However, I'd still recommend it to someone who wanted to consolidate timers from Freshbooks, Harvest, etc. all in one app.