# Make OS X Dashboard Widgets appear in Desktop

Tags: macos, dashboard-widget, dashboard

Dashboard Widgets would be much more useful as MenuBar apps, but some aren't. Is there a way to force OS X to display active Widgets in the MenuBar or as application windows?

Comment: No. Widgets and menu bar icons are programmed differently. Any widget that happens to have a menu bar icon is because the programmer chose to do so.

Comment: I also found that under System Preferences → Mission Control, there's a setting for displaying Dashboard "As Overlay", which is a step in the direction I want to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [WidgetRunner](http://db.lcs.mit.edu/madden/WidgetRunner/) you can run OS X widgets as desktop apps, but not menu bar apps.

Comment: Great tip. This is exactly what I was looking for.